# Is it bad practice to set a properties directly in __construct?

Tags: php, oop

Is it bad practice to set properties directly in `__construct`. Is one of these code blocks better practice for Object Oriented PHP?

I know it is bad practice to do this outside of the class...

```
class person {
    protected $name;

    function __construct($persons_name) {
        $this->set_name($persons_name);
    }
    function set_name($new_name){
        $this->name = $new_name;
    }
}
```

VS.

```
class person {
    protected $name;

    function __construct($persons_name) {
        $this->name = $persons_name;
    }
    function set_name($new_name){
        $this->name = $new_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd argue that `set_name()` is bad practice anyway, since you should be using `__set()`. Others argue that getters & setters are all round bad practice. Take your pick.

Comment: Are there any good books to learn the right way to do PHP OOP?

Comment: `set_name()` is redundant here because your property is public. Why should someone use a method to change it then? Making it protected or private just so you can have a reason to use the method is also not a good idea. Setters are good for properties that have good reasons to be directly inaccessible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both statements are basically OK. There are a small differences you should note:

- The method set_name() is override-able. That means that a function extending the method can alter it's behavior. This is also neither good or bad, you should just think whether you expect your application to do that or not.
- As stated by hek2mgl you can also use the method to perform additional tasks to validate the data generated by the constructor and  avoid duplicate code.
- The second is performance. While you never should code with performance as a priority (always clean and readable code first) it is true that using a method will cost your server a few CPU cycles that may be useful elsewhere.

If you want your application to use the set_name() method and make it 'safe against overriding' you can use the final keyword.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't regarded as bad practice; it will really just depend on what the `set_name($name)` is actually doing.

If you are just setting the value of a variable directly from the argument (such as within your question) then there is a performance cost of the additional function call. This would however be a very small.

If you are however editing/modifying the argument before it is set then it would be best to keep the functionality encapsulated within the method to avoid code duplication.

Comment: The reason not to use a setter method in the OP's question really doesn't have anything to do with performance (we're talking microseconds here) - it has to do with having sensible, readable code. One shouldn't a setter method to update a public property if you already have the property's new value available... why would you write a method when `$this->property=$value;` works? The only caveat I can think of is if you suspect that somewhere down the line you might make the property private or that in the future you might change the property-setting process to involve some more complex logic.

Comment: @BenD My comment regarding performance was not meant to infer this as the primary reason for not using the setter; Just a point to consider, hence the "very small". I agree it *depends* on what is being modified, visibility of the property included.

Answer (score 0):

Although in this example it makes no difference, the second one is "better". This is because normally you would include some validation checks or something like this in the setter method. So, you would just bypass them when directly setting the property.

Another **important** point when thinking about OOP design, is the fact that if you are calling the setter, you offer sub classes the possibility to change that process without need to override the whole constructor

Comment: That might lead to including business logic in your model. Most of the time a setter is just a setter.

Comment: @hek2mgl Do you mean the first one is better, because when `$persons_name` is set by `__construct`, it can validate it the same as the setter?

Comment: Yes, if there is some validation, or even type checks planned to run in setter, why bypassing them? if setters are really only setting the value, without any further checks then you can just use public properties

Comment: Why the downvote? please explain. It's the same as the other answer says (but a minute earlier)

Comment: Yeah I didn't expected that you was that.. :) Its sometimes frustrating when somebody votes down without telling why. I'm 100% behind why I said in the anwer. So it would be interesting to know why someone complains. However, I would call the setter if there is some check logic (or other in it). Doing so you also offer subclasses the way to change that process (important!)

Answer (score 0):

I think, it mostly boils down to personal preferences. However, there are some values you can't set directly to the variable, such as new class instances, that you must assign in the constructor.